# Error while receiving file upload notification from Azure IoT

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, runtime-error, iot

I am facing a very mysterious issue while using Azure IoT service API with Spring Boot application.

I am developing an application where the application will look for any file upload notification on Azure Blob through Azure IoT service. As soon as the file gets uploaded by Azure IoT device, to Azure Blob, through IoT Hub it generates a file upload nofication which we can capture through FileUploadNotificationReceiver class (class of Azure IoT SDK) and we can process this event in our application.

Some points here:

- Initially, I tried and tested the file upload notification process with the help of stand-alone Java application as per the Azure IoT documentation and able to receive and process the notification in this sample application.
- However, when I integrate this code with Spring boot I am getting an error message as **"Service threw something mysteriously dangerous, message abandoned."**

Version details -

- Spring Boot V - 2.1.6.RELEASE
- GSON V 2.8.5

Azure IoT Service client -

- Group ID - com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot
- Artifact ID - iot-service-client    V - 1.17.1

I noticed that this exception message occurs when the FileUploadNotificationReceiver class tries to parse the input JSON received from IoT Hub. The iot-service-client is dependent on GSON dependency. Also, my spring boot application uses GSON dependency. The GSON dependency version is 2.8.5

Any help regarding solve this issue will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Avinash Deshmukh

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I am able  to resolve the issue. 
On the source side, where the file upload API at the Azure IoT device side is used, the blob name was not used correctly. I was using the complete file path as blob name and it was containing the \ (back slash) entry.

You need to change the blob name which will be different from the source file name and it should not have any .